# can not connect to cassandra when using pdo php

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra

I already install `pdo cassandra` and already add in `php.ini`. but when I connect to `cassandra` using php pdo. my web blank (The connection was reset). I check to error log apache, I got child pid 18080 exit signal Segmentation fault.

I am using

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.3 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]   
Thrift version 0.9.0 ubuntu 14.04.1
```

sample connect to cassandra

```
$db = new PDO("cassandra:host=localhost;port=9042;cqlversion=3.2.0", 'cassandra', 'cassandra');
```

*Can anyone tell me how to fix this?*

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error as well?

Comment: this error log in apache  [Tue Mar 17 16:35:47.452909 2015] [core:notice] [pid 19492] AH00051: child pid 20897 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Comment: I've seen this before when nodes are running in a low spec environment, how much memory is assigned to the node? Also it sounds like your nose is never actually up, can you try to restart the cassandra server(s) and verify they are up with cqlsh?

Comment: i try in to my laptop, connect to server, memory capacity is 5 gb up. I've restarted the cassandra and try connect again. the result is same, The connection was reset. if i use cqlsh, the cassandra goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an apache problem rather than a cassandra one. This library is painfully outdated and it doesn't seem to be getting any updates either. The last commit was in Jul 2012:

```
commit d1a1d4bc0a940422e111f37c958170b074b6025a
Author: <we dont need this bit> 
Date:   Fri Jul 13 15:05:22 2012 -0500
...
```

You have two options, find a more updated library, or use a really old version of cassandra. I'd go for the former, planet cassandra has a section for [driver options for various languages](http://planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/#PHP).